# Issue with multiple rows combining into single row

Tags: sql

I have two tables that look like this:

```
Table_X
id, cert_number, other random info

Table_Y
id, cert_number, type, name
```

The issue arises because I have different types in table y that all apply to a single result I want to return (ie: owner name, carrier name, destination name) that are based on the type.

Is there a way that I can combine those into a single result with owner_name, carrier_name, and destination_name?

I used CASE to correctly get the information into the result, but since I use the type field in the select statement, I get back 3 results for each cert_number.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is some sample data. The actual SQL statement is incredibly long due to the large amount of parameters I am required to pass along and check for.

```
table_x
 id  |  cert_number
 1       123-XYZ
 2       124-zyx

table_y
 id  |  cert_number |     type      |  name  
 1       123-XYZ      owner            bob
 2       123-XYZ      destination      paul
 3       124-zyx      owner            steve
 4       123-xyz      carrier          george
 5       124-zyx      carrier          mike
 6       124-zyx      destination      dan
```

Comment: could you provide a few example rows of data and expected output please?

Comment: Give us the SQL of the query you're using and we'll help you improve it. Also, what database are you using? Some of the grouping options that are useful for this sort of thing are database-specific.

Comment: Combine them in what way?

Comment: can you show an example of your query?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?  Also please post the database product you are using and the query that you have tried at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select x.cert_number,
  max(case when y.[type] = 'owner' then y.name end) owner_name,
  max(case when y.[type] = 'carrier' then y.name end) carrier_name,
  max(case when y.[type] = 'destination' then y.name end) destination_name
from table_x x
inner join table_y y
  on x.cert_number = y.cert_number
group by x.cert_number;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e504/1)

Or you can join on your table with the `type` multiple times:

```
select x.cert_number,
  y1.name as owner_name,
  y2.name as carrier_name,
  y3.name as destination_name
from table_x x
left join table_y y1
  on x.cert_number = y1.cert_number
  and y1.type = 'owner'
left join table_y y2
  on x.cert_number = y2.cert_number
  and y2.type = 'carrier'
left join table_y y3
  on x.cert_number = y3.cert_number
  and y3.type = 'destination';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e504/3)

Comment: My case wasn't using the MAX() params. That fixed everything! Thanks :)